# Getting error after placing following code in controller

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart-3

I am trying to create the multi-seller module in Opencart... Everything works great but when I am trying to echo the category I am getting the blank page... the model looks perfect but, I do have little confusion in the controller file... I just pasted controller the code below.

```
$seller_product_total = $this->model_sellerprofile_sellerprofile->getTotalProducts();
$results = $this->model_sellerprofile_sellerprofile->getSellerGroups($filter_data);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data['seller_groups'][] = array(
          'seller_group_id' => $result['seller_group_id'],
          'seller_categories' => $this->model_sellerproduct_category->getCategories(''),
          'name' => $result['name'],
          'sort_order' => $result['sort_order'],
          'description' => $result['description'],
          'product_limit' => ($result['product_limit'] != "0") ? $result['product_limit'] :  $this->language->get('text_unlimited') ,
          'text_subscription_duration' => sprintf($this->language->get('text_subscription_duration'), $result['subscription_duration']),
          'subscription_price' => $this->currency->format($result['subscription_price'], $this->session->data['currency']),
          'subscription_duration' => $result['subscription_duration'],
          'commission' => $this->currency->format($result['commission'], $this->session->data['currency']).' + '.$result['fee']."%",
          'categories' => $this->model_sellerproduct_category->getsellergroupCategoriesByGroupId($result['seller_group_id']),
    );
}
```

and the twig file is as follows

```
<td class="left">
    <div id="seller-group-category" class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
        {% if seller_group.categories is not empty %}
            {% for category in seller_group.seller_categories %}
                {% if category.category_id in seller_group.categories %}
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{ category.name }}</div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <div><i class="fa fa-check"></i>{{ entry_all_categories }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</td>
<td class="left">
    {% if seller_group.categories is not empty %}
        <div class="scrollbox scrollbox{{ '-' .  seller_group.seller_group_id }}" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; width: 350px; height: 150px; background: #FFFFFF; overflow-y: scroll;">
            {% for category in seller_group.seller_categories %}
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        {% if category.category_id in seller_group.categories %}
                            <input type="checkbox" name="seller_category[]" value="{{ category.category_id }}" checked="checked" />
                            {{ category.name }}
                        {% else %}
                            <input type="checkbox" name="seller_category[]" value="{{ category.category_id }}" />
                            {{ category.name }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </label>
                </div>
            % endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</td>
```

Comment: You have a comma after: 'categories' => $this->model_sellerproduct_category->getsellergroupCategoriesByGroupId($result['seller_group_id']). Have you tried removing that? It should not be there if it's the last item in the array.